# create subtitles track by automatic timing of existing text

Tags: video, audio, premiere, conversion, subtitles

1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:04,000

I am using Adobe Premiere to produce videos in English by gluing together multiple clips put together from lots of different footage or sources. I do have a text transcript of what is being said though, in English, so talking about word-for-word English subtitles for the voice in English.

2
00:00:04,250 --> 00:00:06,250

How would I go about creating a subtitles file for the final video?

- I do not wish to render the captions into the video
- The transcript I have does not have any time information and that is the crux of this question - **what is the easiest way to generate semi-accurate timing records, as automatically as possible**?
- So the question is NOT about how to sync existing subtitles with existing timestamps
- I could do it in Premiere, or Adobe Audition, or [Subtitle Edit](http://nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/), Subtitle Workshop or [any other subtitle editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_editor) that may provide relevant synchronization functionality?
- The end result I'm hoping for is a flv file with closed captioning (.sub, .srt or similar) that could be turned on or off in a web-browser / Flash player
- [Like this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbmf0bB38h0), for example, when you click on CC and choose the embedded English subtitling ([not the automatic captions that YouTube offers](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=2734693&guide=2734661&page=guide.cs))

Comment: I know there is an analyze option that does language recognition in Premiere that may be able to help.  I believe it can take a script file as well to produce closed captioning.  I do not know off the top of my head how it works however, but if I have a chance, I'll try messing around with it tonight and see if I can get a workable result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select your clip and go to the Clip menu, then choose Analyse Content, Premiere will attempt to identify speakers and even attempt to dictate what is being said.  You can assist this analysis by providing a script file to it by adding either an Adobe Story Script file or a TXT file to the Reference Script option.  I don't have any experience with how well this feature works, but it's certainly worth a shot if you already have an accurate script file to try it with.

Comment: havent tested it yet, but that sounds like it will work!

Comment: managed to get [a valid astx transcript file from Adobe Story Free](http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/speech-analysis-premiere-pro/), but the very last stage in [Media Encoder did not work as expected](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/847598), and due to lack of troubleshooting time, ended up using [YouTube facility instead](http://jensontaylor.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/guide-to-youtube-captions-subtitles-and.html), which works for videos up to 15 min long :)

Comment: According to this [article from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/speech-analysis.html#Workaround), the above approach won't work anymore because Adobe removed the feature. I just checked on Adobe Premiere CC 2020 – the feature is still removed. Can't believe that there aren't any other solutions in 2019!

Answer (score 1):

Try to publish your video on youtube and add 'Titles' as plain text file. It will be synced automatically if language is supported by Google voice input.

Comment: thats what i ended up doing (see comment to aj henderson), and you can validate to do more than 15 minute clips